# jQuery , datatables converting cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use a DataTables plugin of jquery (www.datatables.net). How to convert cells like

```
name www
n1   w1
n2   w2
n3   w3
name www
```

becames to

```
name www
n1   <a href="w1">w1</a>
n2   <a href="w2">w2</a>
n3   <a href="w3">w3</a>
name www
```

Installing code in jquery is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable();
   $('#example').convertCell(setCell("<a href="getCell()">getCell()</a>"));//How to put it better?
});
```

and html code is a

```
<div id="dynamic">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="15%">Name</th>
            <th width="15%">Www</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Regards: beginner in datatables

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the plugin, but you could use:

```
$('.example').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap(function() {
        return '<a href="' + $(this).text() + '" />';
    });
});
```

Would wrap each element with the class `.example` in a link pointing to the text of each.

Comment: i found myself  "aoColumnDefs": [
{
"aTargets":[1],
"fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
$(nTd).html('<a href="">'+sData+'</a>')}}